# Fibonacci number not starting where it should

Tags: java, fibonacci

I'm attempting to utilize a for loop in order to make a fibonacci sequence and unfortunately when I run the method (listed below), it does not start at 0 as it should. The first number is always 2 when it should be 0. If anyone could explain to me how to make the sequence begin with 0, that would be great. Thank you.

```
public static final void fibonacci(){
    int num = 1;
    int num2 = 1; 
    int tnum = 0; 
    int startnum = 1; 
    System.out.println("Please input a number:"); 
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
    int x = input.nextInt(); 
    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){ 
        System.out.print(num + num2 + " "); 
        tnum = num; 
        num = num2; 
        num2 = tnum + num2; 
    }
}
```

Comment: `num = 1`, `num2 = 1`, then you're outputting `num + num2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start with

```
num = 0
```

and then print num, and modifying num (then in your i-th loop, num is the i-th fibonacci number :

```
public static final void fibonacci() {
    int num = 0;
    int num2 = 1;
    int tnum = 0;
    int startnum = 1;
    System.out.println("Please input a number:"); 
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
    int x = input.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        System.out.print(num);
        tnum = num + num2;
        num = num2;
        num2 = tnum;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final void fibonacci(){
    int num = -1; //was "1"
    int num2 = 1; 
    int tnum = 0; 
    int startnum = 1; 
    System.out.println("Please input a number:"); 
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
    int x = input.nextInt(); 
    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){ 
        System.out.print(num + num2 + " "); 
        tnum = num; 
        num = num2; 
        num2 = tnum + num2; 
    }
}
```

here is the output i got:

*Please input a number:

9

0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21*